# Uncheck other checkbox when checkbox is checked

Tags: flutter, dart

(edited)I have a checkbox which basically is to show a selection of colours to the user so he can select a colour for a product he wants to purchase... Now I'm having difficulties ensuring the other checkbox is unchecked as soon as another checkbox is checked. Any help will be appreciated...My code:

```
   import 'package:.../widgets/app_button.dart';
import 'package:dots_indicator/dots_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:iconly/iconly.dart';
import '../../common/values/app_colors.dart';
import '../../services/product/fetc_product_price.dart';
import '../../services/product/fetch_product_details.dart';
    
        class ProductDetails extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
          final String inventoryId;
          final String price;
        
          const ProductDetails({super.key,  required this.inventoryId, required this.price, });
        @override
          ConsumerState<ProductDetails> createState() => _ProductDetailsState();
        }
        class _ProductDetailsState extends ConsumerState<ProductDetails> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
          late TabController _controller;
         late List<bool> _colorSelected;
        
          @override
          void initState() {
        _controller =  TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    
        super.initState();
     
    
         }
        @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            bool isColorSelected = false;
        return Container(
          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              body: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 30.h,
                  left: 20.w,
                  right: 20.w,
                  bottom: 30.h,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                            color: AppColors.grey7,
                            size: 18.sp,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 8.w,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Product Details',
                          style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: AppColors.grey6,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        Card(
                          shadowColor: Colors.black,
                          elevation: 0.5,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 16.r,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: Icon(
                              IconlyBold.buy,
                              color: const Color(0xff200E32),
                              size: 20.sp,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.h,
                    ),
    
               
    
             FutureBuilder(
                    future: FetchProductDetails().getDetails(widget.inventoryId),
                    builder: (context,snapshot){

                      if(snapshot.data !=  null){
                        final data = snapshot.data as Map<String,dynamic>;
                        final colors =data['colors'];
                        _colorSelected = List<bool>.filled(colors.length, false, growable: false);
                        void checkPrice(Map colorCode){
                        List price = data['prices'];
                     var finalPrice =  price.where((element) => element['colorId'] == colorCode['inventoryColorId']).toList();
                     print(finalPrice);
                        }
                        return Expanded(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Image.asset(
                                          height: 204.h,
                                          width: 342.w,
                                          'assets/images/product_1.png',
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Positioned(
                                      bottom: 0.h,
                                      top: 175.h,
                                      right: 0.w,
                                      left: 0.w,
                                      child: DotsIndicator(
                                        position: 0,
                                        decorator: DotsDecorator(
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.r),
                                          ),
                                          sizes: [
                                            Size(10.w, 3.0.h),
                                            Size(10.w, 3.0.h),
                                            Size(10.w, 3.0.h),
                                            Size(10.w, 3.0.h),
                                          ],
                                          color: AppColors.grey1,
                                          activeColor: Colors.white,
                                          size: const Size.square(9.0),
                                          activeSize: Size(30.w, 3.0.h),
                                          activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.r),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        dotsCount: 4,
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20.h,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      data['inventoryName'],
                                      style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: AppColors.grey5,
                                          fontSize: 20.sp,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const Spacer(),
                          isColorSelected == false?
                          Text(
                            "₦${widget.price}",
                            style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                              textStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.grey5,
                                fontSize: 20.sp,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ):
                          Text(
                            "₦${widget.price}",
                            style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                              textStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.grey5,
                                fontSize: 20.sp,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 8.h,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'Store:',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16.sp,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5.w,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      data['store'],
                                      style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16.sp,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            color: AppColors.grey6),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 12.h,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 28.h,
                                      child: ListView.builder(
                                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                          itemCount: colors.length,
                                          itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                            final hex = colors[index]['code'];
                                            String color = hex.replaceAll('#', '0xff');
                                            return  Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                StatefulBuilder(
                                                    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                                                      return Transform.scale(
                                                        scale: 1.5.h,
                                                        child: Checkbox(
                                                          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                                                          side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
                                                                (states) => const BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                                                          ),
                                                          fillColor:MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                                                            // If the button is pressed, return green, otherwise blue
                                                            if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                                                              return Color(int.parse(color));
                                                            }
                                                            return Color(int.parse(color));
                                                          }),
                                                          overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                                                            // If the button is pressed, return green, otherwise blue
                                                            if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                                                              return Color(int.parse(color));
                                                            }
                                                            return Color(int.parse(color));
                                                          }),
                                                          activeColor: AppColors.primaryColor6,
                                                          value: _colorSelected[index],
                                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                                            setState((){
                                                              _colorSelected[index] = val!;
                                                              isColorSelected =true;
                                                            });
                                                            checkPrice( colors[index]);

                                                          },
                                                        ),
                                                      );
                                                    }
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            );

                                          }),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
        
                                            ],),
                                        ),
        
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }else{
                                print(snapshot.error);
                                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                              }
                        })
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: That's called a "radio button", supported nicely by material and cupertino widgets.

Comment: essentially you can just a simple loop and toggle everything to false. Can you [edit] your question to include the full screen? and make the code runanble

Comment: can radio button be styled exactly like a checkbox tho ?